# How can I solve this integration problem which have a product over the variable

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

I have to solve following integration problem:
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \eta^*(k) \partial_k \eta(k) dk$$
where $\eta^*(k)$ is conjugate of $\eta(k)$ and
$$\eta(k)=\prod_{k=-\pi}^\pi\exp[{ia\cos(k)}]$$ 
with $a$ is constant. I am confused about $\prod_k$.

**My attempt:**

as 
$$\partial_k\eta(k)=i a \cos(k) \exp[{ia\cos(k)}]$$
so
$$I=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \prod_{k=-\pi}^\pi ia \cos(k) dk$$
How to deal with product over $k$?

Comment: What does the star mean in $\eta ^*?$

Comment: conjugate of $\eta$

Comment: Is this for a course?  Does it say anything in the textbook?  I've never seen the $\Pi$ notation used for anything but a product, and of course integrating and differentiating with respect to the index doesn't make much sense.  Is this just garden variety complex variables?

Comment: It's not from any course. Actually it's a simplified form of an other problem.
I have a wavefunction (from Quantum mechanics) $|\psi \rangle = \prod_k \exp{[a \cos{k}]}$ and I want to find a quantity which is defined as $\int dk \langle \psi | \partial_k|\psi\rangle $

Comment: Okay, I don't know anything at all about that.

Comment: Ahan, Okay. Thank you.